# Print name if parameter passed to function

Tags: bash

I have written a little function that exits if the value of the function argument is empty, I would like to be able to also print the name of the parameter (not the value!) if it is possible, my following implementation fails to print the name of the parameter.

```
function exitIfEmpty()
{
        if [ -z "$1" ]
        then
        echo "Exiting because ${!1} is empty"
        exit 1
        fi
}
```

when called like so

`exitIfEmpty someKey`

should print

```
Exiting because someKey is empty
```

Comment: Wait, when you give it "someKey", $1 won't be empty. If it's empty, there's nothing to print.

Comment: @choroba I want to print the parameter name if possible not its value.

Comment: What do you mean by the name? Function arguments don't have names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What gets passed to the function is just a string. If you run `func somevar`, what is passed is the string `somevar`. If you run `func $somevar`, what is passed is (the word-split) value of the variable `somevar`. Neither is a variable reference, a pointer or anything like that, they're just strings.

If you want to pass the *name* of a variable to a function, and then look at the *value* of that variable, you'll need to use a nameref (Bash 4.3 or later, IIRC), or an indirect reference `${!var}`. `${!var}` expands to the value of the variable whose name is stored in `var`.

So, you just have it the wrong way in the script, if you pass the name of a variable to function, use `"${!1}"` to get the *value* of the variable named in `$1`, and plain `"$1"` to get the *name*.

E.g. this will print `variable bar is empty, exiting`, and exit the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
exitIfEmpty() {
    if [ -z "${!1}" ]; then
        echo "variable $1 is empty, exiting"
        exit 1
    fi
}
foo=x
unset bar
exitIfEmpty foo
exitIfEmpty bar
```

Comment: Also: `: "${!1:?Variable $1 is empty or unset}"`.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the name as second argument

```
function exitIfEmpty()
{
        if [ -z "$1" ]
        then
        echo "Exiting because ${2} is empty"
        exit 1
        fi
}

exitIfEmpty "$someKey" someKey
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Exiting because \$1 is empty"
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Wouldn't this always print `Exiting because  is empty`, if the test is against `$1` also? That doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: ITYM `echo 'Exit because $1 is empty'` or `echo "Exit because \$1 is empty"` -- single-quote strings don't do variable expansion; double-quoted strings require `$` to be escaped